# MVC unable to submit and save data from partial view using ajax.beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, but I have been making some changes to an existing code that was created by another group.

There is a User Data view with several partial views, and I want to update the "Profile" section 
(name, phone, etc). The thing is that clicking on the "save" button does nothing; setting a breakpoint on the 
controller doesn't even show the site reaching that code.

These are the main portions of the current code.

"User Detail" view:

```
@model UserDetailsModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ApplicationLayout.cshtml";
}

...

<h2>User Details</h2>
...
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="js-side-nav" data-spy="affix">
        <li class="active"><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#userdevices">Functions</a></li>
...
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="span10">
    <ul class="unstyled">
        <li id="profile">
            <h3>Profile</h3>
            @Html.Partial("_UserProfile", Model.ProfileModel)
            <hr />
        </li>
        <li id="functions">
            <h3>Functions</h3>
            @Html.Partial("_UserFunctions", Model.FunctionsModel)
            <hr />
        </li>
...
```

"User Profile" partial view:

// (I added HttpMethod = "Post")

```
@model UserProfileModel

<section id="user-profile-section">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserProfile", "UserDetail", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "user-profile-section", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel("CustomForm")
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save Profile"/>
}
</section>
```

"User Detail" controller:

//(I added [System.Web.Http.HttpPost])

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserProfile(Guid userId, [FromBody] UserProfileModel model)
{
if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    throw new Exception("Expecting ajax request");

if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return PartialView("_UserProfile", model);

var service = new UserService();
    WebUser user = service.GetUserProfile(userId, SessionState.ApplicationId);
    Mapper.DynamicMap(model, user.Profile, model.GetType(), user.Profile.GetType());
    service.UpdateUser(user);

return PartialView("_UserProfile", model);
}
```

"User Profile" model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace UserDetail
{
public class UserProfileModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string ContactLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Business Phone")]
    public string ContactBusinessPhone { get; set; }

...
```

ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are set to TRUE on the web.config.

I would first like to get the code reach the UserProfile section in the controller, so that I can then
make sure the service.UpdateUser() method works. I have checked, searched and tried several options
and I haven't found what I am missing. In the end, obviously, I want to be able to update the data.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: if I add @Html.Action("UserProfile") to the view, I can reach the code but get an "expecting Ajax request" error.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet you have some field failing validation, but it does not have a corresponding validation message or is hidden, and thus you are not seeing the error.  Perhaps to test this just remove the entire contents of the form except for the submit button and see if it successfully submits.

Another thing to try just as a troublehshooting step, is change(copy it to a comment to be restored after testing) this

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserProfile", "UserDetail", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "user-profile-section", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))`

...to a simple Html.BeginForm, just to determine/rule out the possibility that something is wrong with the AJAX here, perhaps not able to find the UpdateTargetId.

Also, open F12 on Chrome, switch to console tab, refresh page and submit, to see if any javascript errors appear.

Lastly, try removing the [FromBody] attribute temporarily as a test.  Some attributes effect routing, and I'm not sure if this one will, as I've never used it.

Comment: OK. We are moving places now. Changed to Html.BeginForm and I see now that the "userId" parameter sent to the controller's action result is null. Trying to find out now how/where to set it. It is part of the URL.

Comment: Use F12 in chrome, under Elements tab, then Ctrl+F to search for `userId` to see if there is a hidden element inside the form.  If not, there's an overload of BeginForm that takes a routeValues parameter, to which you pass `new { userId =Model.UserId }` assuming it is available from your model.  These route values get added to the form as part of the form submit URL(you can view the generated HTML in the browser to see how it formats it).

Comment: It is working now. Here is what I changed-> 1) added this to the model, so that I could pass it on to the controller but not show it on the view: [Display(Name = "")] [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)] public string UserId { get; set; } 2) Modified the first parameter in the controller so that it reads the value from the URL: [FromUri] Guid userId 3) Added this at the end of the Ajax.BeginForm to send the parameter: new { userId = Model.UserId }